# OSX Sever VPN - Access services that are running on the VPN Server

Tags: vpn, mac-osx-server

I have configured VPN on our OSX Server, and I can connect to the server via the VPN Client. I see no way of actually accessing the services that are running on the VPN Server (apache as a simple test). The server has an external ip address, but no internal IP address on the same subnet as what's being used for the VPN range.

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

Found the answer to this. I added an alias to the loopback adapter:
ifconfig lo0 alias 198.168.1.1